# How to add multiple legends in doughnut chart in chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to generate two different legends for two different datasets in doughnut chat of chart.js however I'm having problem achieving that. I was unable to find any valid answers anywhere. How Can it be done?

[This is how it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JjgS.png)

> ```
>   var config = {
>     type: 'doughnut',
>     data: {
>         datasets: [
>             /* Outer doughnut data*/
>             {
>                 data: [10, 20, 30, 40],
>                 backgroundColor: [
>                     'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
>                     'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
>                     'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
>                     'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)'
>                 ],
>                 label: 'Personal'
>             },
>             /* Outer doughnut data ends*/
>             /* Inner doughnut data*/
>             {
>                 data: [45, 25, 11, 20],
>                 backgroundColor: [
>                     'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
>                     'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
>                     'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
>                     'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
>                 ],
>                 label: 'Benchmark'
>             }
>             /* Inner doughnut data ends*/
>         ],
>         labels: [
>             "Food & Groceries",
>             "Home & Utilities",
>             "Personal & Medical",
>             "Children"
>         ]
>     },
>     options: {
>         responsive: true,
>         legend: {
>             position: 'right',
>         },
>         title: {
>             display: true,
>             text: 'Total Weekly spend $800'
>         },
>         animation: {
>             animateScale: true,
>             animateRotate: true
>         },
>
>         tooltips: {
>             callbacks: {
>                 label: function (item, data) {
>                     console.log(data.labels, item);
>                     return data.datasets[item.datasetIndex].label + ": " + data.labels[item.index] + ": " + data.datasets[item.datasetIndex].data[item.index];
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> };
> window.onload = function () {
>     var ctx = document.getElementById("expensesBreakdown")
>         .getContext("2d");
>     window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx, config);
> };
> ```

[This is what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PHpO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check This Out: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/other-charts/multi-series-pie.html

This is a multilayered pie chart, you can use transparent colors at the middle to achieve the intended outcome.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).